# how to call a javascript fn in Update panel on Partial postback in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
       <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Holder" OnLoad="" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
                <ContentTemplate>
...
                   <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="Timer_Tick" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
          r.init();
        };
```

when the page loads the r.init() [to draw graph] is executed. But when the page partial post back happens the graph is not drawn again. How to fire the JS when the update panel isFinite updated

Comment: Not sure about ASP, but in JSF you would just hook into the ajax lifecycle and register a callback upon response to the partial submit.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to respond to these events that the upload panel will invoke before and after a partial postback.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(...);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(...);
```

Comment: How to insert this in the code, should I call a method when update panel loads

Comment: You'll want to setup these events anytime before the partial postback is invoked. In the past I've added calls to wire up these handlers on the button click that is invoking the partial postback. You could also add it to your document.load code.

Answer (score 1):

Copy of: [Asp.net page life cycle error,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637682/asp-net-page-life-cycle-error)?

Your site has an asp:ScriptManager. This control communicates with the PageRequestManager object in Javascript. You can hook into all communications of updatepanels with your code.

- beginRequest
- endRequest
- initializeRequest
- pageLoaded
- pageLoading

I think pageLoaded is the best for your approach.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
  // PageLoad for sync only
  r.init();
}; 

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function(sender, args) {
  // PageLoad for sync and async!
  r.init();
});
</script>
```

You can extend the code to check which control caused the post in order to optimize your code.

MSDN: [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add endrequest handler to ur updatepanel

Check this link : http://codethatworkedforme.blogspot.com/2011/08/having-issues-with-update-panel.html

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way i found was adding this javascript in the head tag:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" >
            function pageLoad() {
                alert('this executes after each partial post back');
                r.init();
            }
        </script>
</head>
```

The scriptmanager recognizes the pageLoad function and calls it after each partial post back

Source: http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/ (Section: Sometimes, pageLoad() is exactly what you want)