# Asp.net page life cycle error,

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, page-lifecycle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to call a javascript fn in Update panel on Partial postback in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636904/how-to-call-a-javascript-fn-in-update-panel-on-partial-postback-in-asp-net)

update panel is doing partial post back, and I have a Timer_Tick method where I call the method to do data binding and updatepanel onLoad for some calculation for graph. I use a Javascript 
            to draw the graph

```
 window.onload = function () {
      r.init();
    };
```

SO the graph is displayed when the page loads, when the update panel updates after 4 seconds the r.init is not called. I tried many things. the graph disappears.
 can someone give me a example of how to execute the JavaScript after the page partial postback.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Holder" OnLoad="Graphstats" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
                <ContentTemplate>
...
                   <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="Timer_Tick" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: This is almost identical to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636904/how-to-call-a-javascript-fn-in-update-panel-on-partial-postback-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

I believe that within Timer_Tick, you need to set it up to call that script again when it's rendered using RegisterStartupScript.

```
string script = "<script type=text/javascript>r.init();</";
script+= "script>";

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GraphInit", script);
```

[ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your site has an asp:ScriptManager. This control communicates with the PageRequestManager object in Javascript. You can hook into all communications of updatepanels with your code.

- beginRequest
- endRequest
- initializeRequest
- pageLoaded
- pageLoading

I think pageLoaded is the best for your approach.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
  // PageLoad for sync only
  r.init();
}; 

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function(sender, args) {
  // PageLoad for sync and async!
  r.init();
});
</script>
```

You can extend the code to check which control caused the post in order to optimize your code.

MSDN: [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523.aspx)